# How allocate memory to variable referenced by pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

How allocate memory to variable referenced by pointer in C?

This code does not work correctly to me.
After malloc pBitmap is 0x600020 "" . I can assign only first character, but on the attempt to assign more characters it will crash so it's evident that there is not memory correctly allocated.

```
int bmp_read_file(char * filename, BMPFILE *bmpfile, ...)
{
  int num; bool loadbitmap;  char ** pBitmap;
  // this code is kinda shorten
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, num);
  loadbitmap = va_arg(ap, bool);
  pBitmap = va_arg(ap, char ** );
  va_end(ap);
  if (loadbitmap == 1){
      *pBitmap = (char *) malloc( bmpfile->dib.raster_size );
      // pBitmap is 0x600020 ""
      *pBitmap[0]='1';
      *pBitmap[1]='4'; // pBitmap is 0x600020 "1"
      fclose(fp);
  }
  else
    fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

I am calling it like this:

```
  BMPFILE *bmpfile;
  bool loadbitmap = true;
  char * buffer; // bitmap buffer needed to be allocated
  bmp_read_file(argv[1],&bmpfile,loadbitmap,&buffer);
```

Comment: '123' is far from being character or even string...You might want use `strcpy` and DOUBLE quotes enclosed string literals

Comment: As @EugeneSh. says, this doesn't even compile.

Comment: What is `*pBitmap[0]='123';` supposed to do? Copy the string `"123"`? Assign a character of numeric value `123`? But mainly, why are you complicating things with a variable number of function arguments?

Comment: And did it compile without warnings?

Comment: @Weather Vane: what's wrong with variable number of arguments?

Comment: Because to read a bitmap you need specific information, not an optional list. Why don't you just pass the info as required arguments?

Comment: Seeing as `*bmpfile` is already a pointer shouldn't you be passing `bmpfile` and not `&bmpfile`?

Comment: You mean pass struct with  file name etc. That's good idea.

Comment: @Weather Vane: I use &buffer in function call argument when I want the function to update the buffer. I think that it would update it locally if I would use just buffer and local char * ... I am still beginner with pointers but this way it works for me. I tried different ways which did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
  *pBitmap[0]='1';
  *pBitmap[1]='4'; // pBitmap is 0x600020 "1"
```

To:

```
  (*pBitmap)[0]='1';
  (*pBitmap)[1]='4'; // pBitmap is 0x600020 "1"
```

Right now, your code is doing the equivalent of `*(pBitmap[0]) = '1'` which doesn't make any sense given the way you have allocated `*pBitmap`.

Comment: Well, it might make sense given pBitmap is array of pointers (like `*argv[]` for instance)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the pointer as `pointer[1]` oder use it as `*(pointer + 1)` to access the element with index 1. Acordingly of course for any other index replace the 1. 
 Unless you have an array of pointers `*pointer[1]` won't work.

Comment: I asked how to allocate memory not how to access an element

Comment: Yes, but your memory allocation is right as far as I can see. Don't have the possibility to test right now.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you asked:

> what's wrong with variable number of arguments?

The function can be simplified quite a bit if you don't use variable number of arguments.

```
int bmp_read_file(char * filename,
                  BMPFILE *bmpfile,
                  bool loadbitmap,
                  char** pBitmap);
{
   if (loadbitmap == 1)
   {
      *pBitmap = malloc( bmpfile->dib.raster_size );
      (*pBitmap)[0]='1';
      (*pBitmap)[1]='4';
   }

   // fclose(fp); 
   // Not sure why you have that in your function. There is no
   // variable fp and there is no call to fopen().

   return 0;
}
```

**Update**

On thinking it a little bit more, you can remove the `loadbitmap` argument altogether.

```
int bmp_read_file(char * filename,
                  BMPFILE *bmpfile,
                  char** pBitmap);
{
   if (pBitmap != NULL)
   {
      *pBitmap = malloc( bmpfile->dib.raster_size );
      (*pBitmap)[0]='1';
      (*pBitmap)[1]='4';
   }

   return 0;
}
```

When you don't need to header information, you can simply use:

```
BMPFILE *bmpfile;
bmp_read_file(argv[1],&bmpfile,NULL);
```

Comment: Notice that the code was shorten. The reason why I choose variable number of arguments is that in the case that I want only to read the file header and not the bitmap, then I dont need to create the variables needed for `bool loadbitmap, char** pBitmap`

Comment: When you don't need to read the file header, you can use just pass `0` and `NULL` to the function.